# Error in javafx main method for FXML loading not getting rectified

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, controller, fxml

I had a working calculator program created with javafx. However, to improve my program I decide to include keyevents also to input numbers. For this I had to call an instance of my Controller class to pass a parameter from the main class where I record the keyevent to my FXMLController. However after I modified the code, it is not compiling showing up exception in my main class.
It gives **AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader**

Here is the previous working code:

```
public class Mycalc extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Parent root =FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("calc1.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,Color.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }

}
```

Here is the current code (with error):

```
public class Mycalc extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    FXMLLoader loader= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("calc1.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();


    Scene scene = new Scene(root,Color.TRANSPARENT);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    calc1Controller controller= loader.getController();
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) 
        {

            switch (keyEvent.getCode()) 
            {
                case DIGIT1:
                    controller.handleDigit("1");
                    break ;
                case DIGIT2:
                    controller.handleDigit("2");
                    break ;
                case DIGIT3:
                    controller.handleDigit("3");
                    break ;
                case DIGIT4:
                    controller.handleDigit("4");
                    break ;
                case DIGIT5:
                    controller.handleDigit("5");
                    break ;
                case DIGIT6:
                    controller.handleDigit("6");
                    break ;
                case DIGIT7:
                    controller.handleDigit("7");
                    break ;
                case DIGIT8:
                    controller.handleDigit("8");
                    break ;
                case DIGIT9:
                    controller.handleDigit("9");
                    break ;
                case ADD:
                    controller.handleOperatorkey("+");
                    break ;
                case SUBTRACT:
                    controller.handleOperatorkey("-");
                    break ;
                case MULTIPLY:
                    controller.handleOperatorkey("*");
                    break ;
                case DIVIDE:
                    controller.handleOperatorkey("/");
                    break ;
                case EQUALS:
                    controller.handleEqualKey();
                    break ;
            }
        }   
    });
}
```

However I am getting the following message when running:

```
   Exception in Application start method
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
at mycalc.Mycalc.start(Mycalc.java:32)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
... 1 more
    Exception running application mycalc.Mycalc
```

I replaced Parent root with AnchorPane root also but I'm still getting the same error. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader

Instead of:

```
FXMLLoader loader= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("calc1.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
```

try (untested)

```
FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("calc1.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
```

or (if your FXML root element is an AnchorPane):

```
FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("calc1.fxml"));
AnchorPane root = loader.load();
```

`FXMLLoader.load` loads the FXML file. It doesn't return a FXMLLoader.

Comment: Yes, my FXML root is an AnchorPane.But if I need to call an instance of my controller class, I am unable to do with root. It shows error. I need  FXMLLoader loader to initialize the instance.

Comment: @Code_Dummy Sorry, I missed that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I got it working with your solution. Sorry, I didn't realise that mistake. Thanks a lot for the information. I tried the Parent root style and it did run.